# GWT: Login to a password protected third party website

Tags: javascript, gwt, cookies, authentication, web

After searching around a lot, I still can't find the answer to this question: Is it possible to login to a 3rd party website using GWT when the website is password protected?

I'm asking this because I would like to write a Google application that combines information from different websites (My news account, my forums accounts, etc.) ... like a kind of dashboard.
I have no problem doing it for non-password protected websites.
But for websites where you have to login and handle cookies, I'm just lost.

I found this very interesting tutorial that explains how to do it for Java: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

But I can't figure out how to do it with GWT.

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: I think it's possible, but you have to dig into google api documentation. But are you sure about the tag "javascript" ?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about using [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) to send the authentication requests, and follow the tutorial you pointed to.

But after more consideration I guess the Same-Origin-Policy is going to prevent you to do ajax calls to another website from the client side in some browser. You also have to make sure that your domain is in HTTPS before calling remote HTTPS url. And you might run into other problems if you follow that path...

**Conclusion:** I suggest making those calls from the server using plain old java code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.
I wanted to do it from the server side like you suggested. But Google App Engine prevents me from doing so. Or maybe you know a way to do it with GAE?

Comment: Hello, otonglet
The example you send access a url that is not password protected.
What I want to do is access a website that is password protected and uses cookie (with session id) to get information.
A bit like logging to google mail without going through their API (the website I want to connect to doesn't provide any API for it).

Comment: Sorry, just posting a link got us confused. MKYong example uses the same technology (HttpUrlConnection) as does the answer I posted above. I posted it not as a relevant example but  as a hint meaning  "yes, I know a way to do it from the server side with GAE, by reproducing the MKYong tutorial and using HttpUrlConnection, this answer shows this API is also available with GAE".

Comment: Thank you. I will try it this week-end and let you know!

Comment: great ! waiting for your feedback :)

Comment: Hi otonglet! 
I tried ... but unfortunately it didn't work.
The example in your link uses "repackaged" internal classes, that shouldn't be used (say Google) ... and that anyway do not exist anymore in the GAE version I'm using.
So I guess my only choice now is to move to another hosting solution. That's a shame, GAE was a good (and free) prototyping  platform for servlet development. Can you advise me on a hosting plaform for servlet?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry no idea. Try to start a new question.